# Fetching JSON from inside a JSON array

Tags: java, android, json

I have the following JSON

```
"music": [
  {
    "play_offset_ms":10780,
    "artists":[
      {
        "name":"Adele"
      }
    ],
    "lyrics":{
      "copyrights":[
        "Sony/ATV Music Publishing LLC",
        "Universal Music Publishing Group"
      ]
    },
    "acrid":"6049f11da7095e8bb8266871d4a70873",
    "album":{
      "name":"Hello"
    },
    "label":"XL Recordings",
    "external_ids":{
      "isrc":"GBBKS1500214",
      "upc":"886445581959"
    },
    "result_from":3,
    "contributors":{
      "composers":[
        "Adele Adkins",
        "Greg Kurstin"
      ],
      "lyricists":[
        "ADELE ADKINS",
        "GREGORY KURSTIN"
      ]
    },
    "title":"Hello",
    "duration_ms":295000,
    "score":100,
    "external_metadata":{
      "deezer":{
        "track":{
          "id":"110265034"
        },
        "artists":[
          {
            "id":"75798"
          }
        ],
        "album":{
          "id":"11483764"
        }
      },
      "spotify":{
        "track":{
          "id":"4aebBr4JAihzJQR0CiIZJv"
        },
        "artists":[
          {
            "id":"4dpARuHxo51G3z768sgnrY"
          }
        ],
        "album":{
          "id":"7uwTHXmFa1Ebi5flqBosig"
        }
      },
      "musicstory":{
        "track":{
          "id":"13106540"
        },
        "release":{
          "id":"2105405"
        },
        "album":{
          "id":"931271"
        }
      },
      "youtube":{
        "vid":"YQHsXMglC9A"
      }
    },
    "release_date":"2015-10-23"
  }
]
```

I want to fetch the value `vid` from the `youtube` object in `external_metadata`. I am getting other required values but couldn't get the `youtube` `id` with what I tried. Just attaching a code snippet of what I tried.

I tried the following code:

```
 try {
            JSONObject j = new JSONObject(result);
            JSONObject j1 = j.getJSONObject("status");
            int j2 = j1.getInt("code");
            if(j2 == 0){
                JSONObject metadata = j.getJSONObject("metadata");


                //
                if (metadata.has("music")) {
                    wave.setVisibility(View.GONE);
                    JSONArray musics = metadata.getJSONArray("music");
                    for(int i=0; i<musics.length(); i++) {
                        JSONObject tt = (JSONObject) musics.get(i);
                        String title = tt.getString("title");
                        JSONArray artistt = tt.getJSONArray("artists");
                        JSONObject art = (JSONObject) artistt.get(0);
                        String artist = art.getString("name");
                        JSONObject extMETA = tt.getJSONObject("external_metadata");
                        JSONObject youtube = extMETA.getJSONObject("youtube");
                        String ytID = youtube.getString("vid");}}
```

I did not get the expected output with what i tried , i know i am doing something wrong. Need your guidance.

Comment: what output your retrieving right now ?

Comment: i recommend you to use gson library https://github.com/google/gson

Comment: Your code is absolutely fine. Can you show how do you create `metadata` from your json?

Comment: this code is fine. Please post more code block around this.

Comment: Actually this is a example of ACRcloudsdk (audio fingerprinting), i am new to android and i was just playing around this sdk and that json is in their [docs](https://docs.acrcloud.com/docs/acrcloud/metadata/music/) so wanted to use those values for more functionality

Answer (score 1):

I tried to run your code with sample JSON you have provided and It seems to work perfectly fine. I used google's gson library.
Below is the complete code.

```
import com.google.gson.JsonArray;
import com.google.gson.JsonObject;
import com.google.gson.JsonParser;

public class Test {

    static String jsonString = "{ \"music\": [{ \"play_offset_ms\": 10780, \"artists\": [{ \"name\": \"Adele\" }], \"lyrics\": { \"copyrights\": [ \"Sony/ATV Music Publishing LLC\", \"Universal Music Publishing Group\" ] }, \"acrid\": \"6049f11da7095e8bb8266871d4a70873\", \"album\": { \"name\": \"Hello\" }, \"label\": \"XL Recordings\", \"external_ids\": { \"isrc\": \"GBBKS1500214\", \"upc\": \"886445581959\" }, \"result_from\": 3, \"contributors\": { \"composers\": [ \"Adele Adkins\", \"Greg Kurstin\" ], \"lyricists\": [ \"ADELE ADKINS\", \"GREGORY KURSTIN\" ] }, \"title\": \"Hello\", \"duration_ms\": 295000, \"score\": 100, \"external_metadata\": { \"deezer\": { \"track\": { \"id\": \"110265034\" }, \"artists\": [{ \"id\": \"75798\" }], \"album\": { \"id\": \"11483764\" } }, \"spotify\": { \"track\": { \"id\": \"4aebBr4JAihzJQR0CiIZJv\" }, \"artists\": [{ \"id\": \"4dpARuHxo51G3z768sgnrY\" }], \"album\": { \"id\": \"7uwTHXmFa1Ebi5flqBosig\" } }, \"musicstory\": { \"track\": { \"id\": \"13106540\" }, \"release\": { \"id\": \"2105405\" }, \"album\": { \"id\": \"931271\" } }, \"youtube\": { \"vid\": \"YQHsXMglC9A\" } }, \"release_date\": \"2015-10-23\" }] }";

    public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception {
        System.out.println("START");
        readJson(jsonString);

        System.out.println("END");
    }

    public static void readJson(String jsonString) throws Exception {
        JsonObject metadata = new JsonParser().parse(jsonString).getAsJsonObject();
        JsonArray musics = metadata.get("music").getAsJsonArray();
        for (int i = 0; i < musics.size(); i++) {
            JsonObject tt = musics.get(i).getAsJsonObject();

            String title = tt.get("title").getAsString();
            JsonArray artistt = tt.get("artists").getAsJsonArray();
            JsonObject art = artistt.get(0).getAsJsonObject();
            String artist = art.get("name").getAsString();
            JsonObject extMETA = tt.get("external_metadata").getAsJsonObject();
            JsonObject youtube = extMETA.get("youtube").getAsJsonObject();
            String ytID = youtube.get("vid").getAsString();
            System.out.println("ytID => "+ ytID);
        }
    }
}
```

Output: 
[image]

Answer (score 0):

Verify that the metadata variable has its value.

```
JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(json);
Log.e("json structure : ", jsonObject.toString());
```

Use the following code when importing Json File from "Assets".

```
InputStream inputStream = getAssets().open("item.json");
int size = inputStream.available();
byte[] buffer = new byte[size];
inputStream.read(buffer);
inputStream.close();
json = new String(buffer, StandardCharsets.UTF_8);
```

If you have a Gson library, you can also access it in the "Class" format.

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
ItemVO itemVO = gson.fromJson(json, new TypeToken<ItemVO>() {
}.getType());
if (!itemVO.name != null) {
  Log.e("name : ", itemVO.name);
} else {
  Log.e("name : ", "name is Null");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Actual problem is in your `JSONObject` creation from sample data. Check below:

```
String data = "{\"metadata\":{\"timestamp_utc\":\"2020-01-02 09:40:56\",\"music\":[{\"play_offset_ms\":10780,\"artists\":[{\"name\":\"Adele\"}],\"lyrics\":{\"copyrights\":[\"Sony/ATV Music Publishing LLC\",\"Universal Music Publishing Group\"]},\"acrid\":\"6049f11da7095e8bb8266871d4a70873\",\"album\":{\"name\":\"Hello\"},\"label\":\"XL Recordings\",\"external_ids\":{\"isrc\":\"GBBKS1500214\",\"upc\":\"886445581959\"},\"result_from\":3,\"contributors\":{\"composers\":[\"Adele Adkins\",\"Greg Kurstin\"],\"lyricists\":[\"ADELE ADKINS\",\"GREGORY KURSTIN\"]},\"title\":\"Hello\",\"duration_ms\":295000,\"score\":100,\"external_metadata\":{\"deezer\":{\"track\":{\"id\":\"110265034\"},\"artists\":[{\"id\":\"75798\"}],\"album\":{\"id\":\"11483764\"}},\"spotify\":{\"track\":{\"id\":\"4aebBr4JAihzJQR0CiIZJv\"},\"artists\":[{\"id\":\"4dpARuHxo51G3z768sgnrY\"}],\"album\":{\"id\":\"7uwTHXmFa1Ebi5flqBosig\"}},\"musicstory\":{\"track\":{\"id\":\"13106540\"},\"release\":{\"id\":\"2105405\"},\"album\":{\"id\":\"931271\"}},\"youtube\":{\"vid\":\"YQHsXMglC9A\"}},\"release_date\":\"2015-10-23\"}]},\"cost_time\":0.2110002040863,\"status\":{\"msg\":\"Success\",\"version\":\"1.0\",\"code\":0},\"result_type\":0}";

try {
    JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(data);
    JSONObject metadata = jsonObject.getJSONObject("metadata");

    JSONArray musics = metadata.getJSONArray("music");
    for (int i = 0; i < musics.length(); i++) {
        JSONObject tt = (JSONObject) musics.get(i);
        String title = tt.getString("title");
        JSONArray artistt = tt.getJSONArray("artists");
        JSONObject art = (JSONObject) artistt.get(0);
        String artist = art.getString("name");
        JSONObject extMETA = tt.getJSONObject("external_metadata");
        JSONObject youtube = extMETA.getJSONObject("youtube");
        String ytID = youtube.getString("vid");

        Log.v("VID", ytID);
    }
} catch (Exception ex) {
    ex.printStackTrace();
}
```

Comment: @amolsawrikar, Check answer here

Comment: I'll  edit the code and show how i created json object, please check.

Comment: What did you get in `ytID`?

Comment: {"status":{"msg":"Success","code"
0,version":"1.0)'metadata":{("music":
f'external_ids":( play offset_ms"
115460 external_metadata":(),"score":
79,"release_date":"2016-05-18","title", "Hello
(Remix)",label" "Bujimix
Records",duration_ms":358000 album".
{'name":"Plogué.")},"acrid"."3bdf9a37896c
e7a28b6851d3c14b3e48", "result from".
3,'artists":[{"name":"Bujimix"}]],"timestamp
Lutc". " 2020011307 :35.24) cost time":
0.046000003814697 result_type o}  @Ashish